# Access typedef in classes with an object, not the scope resolution operator (::)

Tags: c++, class, typedef

In the following code, when I try to access the typedef with an instantiated object, it gives me an error, when I access it using the scope resolution operator (::), the program works perfectly. I just wanted to know why.

```
#include <iostream>

class Types {

    public:

        typedef int Integer;

};

int main() {

    Types types;

    types.Integer foo = 1; // <-- Gives me an error

    Types::Integer goo = 2; // <-- Works perfectly fine

    std::cout << foo;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << goo;

    return 0;

}
```

I'm just using this as an example, this is not real code to anything. The error it is giving me is:

```
Line 15 | invalid use of 'Types::Integer'
```

Comment: You can also use `decltype(type)::Integer`

Comment: The Integer is type 's alias name not class member, they require different semantic

Comment: You can only access members of your class with the `.` operator. You use the `::` operator to access static members of your class and typedefs

Comment: @DanielRobertson I can access static members of a class with the "." operator. I don't get why I can't access typedefs...

Comment: Also, when I use an enum instead of a typedef, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Think of it this way... You can access members of a class object via the `.` operator because they belong to the object to which they are assigned. Your `typedef` doesn't belong to your class object `types` it belongs to the class as a whole `Types`. Think of your `typedef` as static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just how the syntax works. `Integer` in that context is a type belonging to the `Types` namespace, and if you want to access that type you have to use `::`. `operator.` is used for member access of objects or functions.

`operator.` allows you to access a member belonging to an instance, while `::` traverses namespaces (allowing you to access static fields, static functions, typedefs, member variables, etc.).

Comment: [@EyasSH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/864313/eyassh) I have no idea why your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7302237) was rejected, but I've found it extremely helpful. Thanks.